# jQuery Fancybox 2 plugin - is there a way to trigger click but just for fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

So when element X has fancybox binded on the click event (already initialized on that element) but that same X element has more on click events attached, I am interested to know if it is possible to trigger the fancybox only.

Will that code do exactly this or it will reinitialize on the target element?

```
jQuery.fancybox(jQuery('#element-x'));
```

For example I imagine something like that to do the task, instead of triggering click event:

```
jQuery('#element-x').trigger('fancybox');
```

Please provide detailed information.

Comment: If an element has several `click` events bound to it, all will trigger. What you could do is to bind several events in a single `click` and pass a parameter in a function to trigger only one programmatically (fancybox in your case)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I am looking for clearer way, such as native fancybox click event without the need to inform other components of how to bind on the click event.

Comment: The native fancybox `click` event will trigger fancybox, but won't prevent other bound `click` events to trigger

Comment: Yeah that is logical ;) I meant a fancy box specific click event will get the job done and not the DOM native click event. So if someone wants to answer that is one of the things to check.

Comment: It is not actually about a click event but event specific/native to the plugin witch had to open it without reinitialize.